# jQuery form validation issue, other box when visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have the below 'other' box. I want to validate the box so its not blank only when it is visible. For what should be straightforward I am having trouble. Any help much appreciated. Thanks

```
    else if($('#myBox_' + id + ':visible')) { if(!blank('otherprodtypebox[<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>]')){alert("Please enter a valid other option");return false;} }


    <script type="text/javascript">
function myOtherBox(e, id) {
    if (e.value == 'otherprodtype')
    {
        $('#myBox_' + id).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#myBox_' + id).hide();
    }

}
</script>

    <tr style="display:none;">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">myBox_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute>
    <td class="Label">Other</td>
    <td>
        <input class="amdInputText" type="text" id="otherprodtypebox" value="">
              <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="otherprodtypebox"></xsl:value-of></xsl:attribute>
        </input>
    </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT:

I nearly have it working now:

```
else if($('#myBox_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>').is(':visible')) { if(!blank('otherprodtypebox[<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>]')){alert("Please enter a valid other option");return false;} }
```

ok so this seems to only check validation when box is visible and throws up the alert if its empty but then for some strange reason when i fill in the box it doesn't throw up the alert as expected but wont let me proceed and no error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replacing `$('#myBox_' + id + ':visible')` with `$('#myBox_' + id).is(':visible')` fixes the problem

Comment: you might see my answer aswell as its &amp;&amp; added to the if also that works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with a combination of things but most importantly the .is(':visible')

Working code:

```
else if(($('#myBox_<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>').is(':visible'))&amp;&amp;(!blank('otherprodtypebox[<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>]'))){alert("Please enter a valid other option");document.lending.otherprodtypebox[<xsl:value-of select="@id"/>].focus();return false; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure but I think this can cause problem(is this returning any result? you can check that):

```
$('#myBox_' + id + ':visible')
```

instead of this you can try to check visible attribute like:

```
$('#myBox_' + id).attr('visible')
```

Comment: seriously? $('#myBox_' + id).is(':visible') is the way it should be done

Comment: @muluturk got it working. thanks for help. can't really accept this answer though as its not a good reference. Pawel_W is right.

Comment: @Pawel_W got it working. thanks for help. Your answer helped but its only a comment so can't give you the points

Comment: @topcat3 ok, so I've added answer for future users looking for the solution

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that `$('#myBox_' + id + ':visible')` is a jQuery selector and thus will return an empty array if no element are matching.

Converting an empty array into a boolean in JavaScript will always return `true`. Therefore `if($('#myBox_' + id + ':visible'))` will always return `true`.

You might use `if($('#myBox_' + id + ':visible').length > 0)` to make sure that your selector has matched at least one element.